# python-social-auth and github, I have this error "The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application"

Tags: python, django, authentication, github, python-social-auth

I'm using python-social-auth on a project to authenticate the user with Github.
I need to redirect the user depending on the link they use. To do that I'm using the next attribute on the url, and I didn't declare any redirect url on my github app neither in my django settings.

This is the href attribute I'm using for my link : `{% url 'social:begin' 'github' %}?next={% url 'apply' j.slug %}`

And the first time I click on it, I'm getting redirected to my homepage with this error in the url field : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fv3%2Foauth%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=Ui1EOKTHDhOkNJESI5RTjOCDEIdfFunt`

But after first time the link work.

I don't know where is the problem, I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library uses [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) for GitHub authentication.

You *must* provide a callback URL, because the OAuth process causes the user's browser to actually *leave your site* as part of the authentication process. The callback URL that you send to GitHub is used to redirect users *back to* your site.

It looks like Python Social Auth [handles some of this for you](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/github.html), though (emphasis mine):

> ### GitHub
>
> Github works similar to Facebook (OAuth).
>
> - Register a new application at [GitHub Developers](https://github.com/settings/applications/new), **set the callback URL to `http://example.com/complete/github/` replacing `example.com` with your domain**.
> - Fill `App Id` and `App Secret` values in the settings:
>
>   ```
>   SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY = ''
>   SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET = ''
>   ```
> - Also it’s possible to define extra permissions with:
>
>   ```
>   SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SCOPE = [...]
>   ```

The tricky bit is getting this to work on your development machine.

Setting your domain to 127.0.0.1 in your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) should work, something like this

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

but make sure to comment this like out once you move into production!

You may also want to browse [GitHub's OAuth documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/). Using a library is great, but if you understand the underlying technology you'll have fewer problems.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the login redirect URI mismatch by just using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: I used this on github when setting the homepage url and the authorization callback url

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the way you've configured the urls.py locally. If you have

```
path('social/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

then your **Authorization callback URL** should be

```
http://localhost/social/complete/github/
```