# error : redirect_uri_mismatch :: The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL

Tags: python-2.7, flask, oauth, github-api

So I am trying to learn OAuth in Flask using Github OAuth API and I am using `flask_dance` library for it. I am able to authenticate myself on Github and return back to my app but in its showing `404 Not Found Error` and in the url its `http://localhost:5000/login/authorized?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application...` , The callback url seems correct as it is what I gave on github but still its showing `redirect_uri mismatch` .
I was reading the documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/apps/managing-oauth-apps/troubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors/#redirect-uri-mismatch) and got to know that we can remove `redirect_uri` parameter from the request but I am not sure how to do that. 
( and I am on Windows 10 )
Any help would be nice. Thanks.

[image: shown here]

### App.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
from flask_dance.contrib.github import make_github_blueprint, github

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
app.secret_key = "supersekrit"
blueprint = make_github_blueprint(
    client_id="xxxxxxxxx",
    client_secret="xxxxxxxx",
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route("/signup")
def index():
    if not github.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("github.login"))
    resp = github.get("/user")
    assert resp.ok
    return "You are @{login} on GitHub".format(login=resp.json()["login"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: [Some people face this in Django too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75300861/5675325)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your callback URL is incorrect - it should be http://localhost:5000/login/github/authorized

[image]

The documentation for Flask-Dance says that the code creates a blueprint "github" with two views "/github" and "/github/authorized". The blueprint is also configured with a url_prefix of "/login" so your callback URL therefore needs to be http://localhost:5000/login/github/authorized.

> This code makes a blueprint that implements the views necessary to be
>   a consumer in the OAuth dance. The blueprint has two views: /github,
>   which is the view that the user visits to begin the OAuth dance, and
>   /github/authorized, which is the view that the user is redirected to
>   at the end of the OAuth dance. Because we set the url_prefix to be
>   /login, the end result is that the views are at /login/github and
>   /login/github/authorized. The second view is the “authorized callback
>   URL” that you must tell GitHub about when you create the application.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, One more problem though, I am not getting redirect_uri mismatch now but in flask debug console i see   "GET /login/github/authorized?code=xxxxxx&state=xxxx  HTTP/1.1" 302  
but on my web page i see 404 Not found as the application goes to  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 , I don't know how can I handle this. If I browse  to "/signup" url my username is coming but i want it to show just after the callback not manually browsing to that url.

Comment: @VivekKumarPathak it looks like you can simply set redirect_url when you call make_github_blueprint. https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html