# Authlib and GitHub. Error "The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback"

Tags: python, github, flask, github-api, authlib

I use authlib to authenticate with github. In developer settings github I set Authorization callback URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/complete`

But everything works very, very strangely, sometimes the authentication works, but more often I get the error:

`authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.OAuthError: redirect_uri_mismatch: The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application.`

Sometimes I can get an error, and then click on the authentication again and everything will work.

My code:

```
from app.authentication.oauth import bp
from flask import url_for, render_template, redirect
from app import oauth

@bp.route('/alogin')
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for('oauth.authorize', _external=True)
    print(redirect_uri)
    return oauth.github.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@bp.route('/complete')
def authorize():
    token = oauth.github.authorize_access_token()
    resp = oauth.github.get('user', token=token) 
    resp.raise_for_status()
    user = resp.json()
    print(token)
    print(user)
    #profile = resp.json()
    # do something with the token and profile
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

In my opinion, the uri matches, but it works very strangely

this question is very similar to mine

[python-social-auth and github, I have this error "The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360160/python-social-auth-and-github-i-have-this-error-the-redirect-uri-must-match-th)

But it can't help with my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @user11717481 My question is correct, I have authlib, a github service, indicated the setting on the service side, and indicated what is happening in my code, and what error I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understood what the problem was. I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost in GitHub app settings. And it works.